About solution to homogeneous ODE $u'' + u = 0$
It is known that the solution to $u'' + u = f(x)$ with $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$ is $$u(x) = \int_0^x\sin(x - \xi)f(\xi)d\xi,$$ where $\sin(x-\xi)$ is a solution to $$\frac{d}{dx}R + R = 0, \ \ \ x > \xi,$$ with $R\mid_{x = \xi} = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}R\mid_{x = \xi} = 1$.
In this case, the solution to the homogeneous $u'' + u = 0$ with $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$ is zero (?) I can not prove this last part.
How do I show that the solution to the homogeneous equation is zero?
Thanks in advance.

You transform it to a system of first order. This has a unique solution for the initial condition $u_1(0) = u_2(0) = 0$ (Picard-Lindelöf). You can easily check that this solution is $0$.

We can check that $u''+u=0$ has the Solution $u=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{+x}$ :
$u'=-c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{+x}$
$u''=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{+x}$
[[ Solving Characteristic Polynomial $D^2+1=0$ , we get $D=+1,D=-1$ , hence the Solution is $u=c_1e^{(+1)x}+c_2e^{(-1)x}$ where we have used those roots. Thanks to user Gonçalo to highlight this. ]]
Starting with $u'(0)=0$ , $u(0)=0$ , we will get
$-c_1+c_2=0$
$c_1+c_2=0$
Adding , we get $c_2=0$
Subtracting , we get $c_1=0$
Due to given Criteria , $u=0$ is the Solution.

Another approach, let $f(x) = u(x)^2+(u'(x))^2$. Then $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 0$ hence $f(x) = 0$.
